# How to load csv with header value that contains a cypher keyword in Neo4j

Tags: database, neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

I am loading a CSV in `neo4j` but a header value named 'intent' is not able to load as properties in below case.

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "filePath" AS row
CREATE (cmd:Command {name: row.command, description: row.description,}), (act:Activity {name: row.intent})
```

because '`IN`' is a keyword in Cypher I guess which is why row. The intent is not get executed properly, please help me with the issue.
Any suggestions.

Comment: Cypher would not get confused by the  "in" at the beginning of "intent". You have a syntax error, as pointed out by @Graphileon's answer, so you need to fix that. Afterwards, if you continue to have a problem, then you need to provide the error message and also at least the first few lines from your data file.

Answer (score 0):

there seems to be an error in your Cypher

```
row.description,}
```

should be

```
row.description}
```

=======

put backticks ?

`INTENT`

That works for us if we have keys like

`$mykey`,`key:ar`,`#somekey`

Comment: is there any other way I can use the name as it is, without making changes in CSV file

Comment: try to isolate the issue. not sure if it's the LOAD CSV or the CREATE statement.

what do you get when, after the LOAD CSV, you do just  'RETURN row LIMIT 5'  ?

Comment: there is also an error in your cypher.. see my answer.

Comment: yeah, that is just typo but I am getting error for the second label I am creating which is (act: Activity {name: row.intent}) because 'in' is a keyword because of that row.intent is not working and I don't want to change the name of that.